# Wordpress plugin works in preview but not in published version

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am using the `WonderPlugin Tabs` plugin. While I am previewing the page it works, but when I am accessing the published version I get errors like :

> Loading failed for the < script > with source ....

You can check the published version here:

http://www.syntexniagr.ipage.com/coffeylab/publications/

the problem is that its looking for the resources under `www.syntexnia.gr/coffeylab` and not under `www.syntexniagr.ipage.com/coffeylab` as it should. How I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The console is displaying a lot of errors, it can't access the resources so your page won't render correctly.

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
>   www.syntexnia.gr/coffeylab/wp-content/plugins/blog-designer/css/designer_css.php
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
>   www.syntexnia.gr/coffeylab/wp-content/plugins/columns/columns.css
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
>   www.syntexnia.gr/coffeylab/wp-content/plugins/constant-contact-forms/assets/css/style.css
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: the problem is that its looking for the resources under www.syntexnia.gr/coffeylab and not under www.syntexniagr.ipage.com/coffeylab as it should